# Eliminar columna de una matriz

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Al pasar una csv a una matriz con pandas me crea una columna a la izuierda de todo indicando el numero de fila que es. ¿Como se podría eliminar?.

```
def cargar():
  print("Indica la ruta donde se encuentra el CSV\n")
  print("Si desea salir pulse '0' " )
ruta=input()
try:
    if ruta=="0":
        sys.exit()

    matriz_partidos=pd.read_csv(ruta,header=0)
    print(matriz_partidos)
    matriz_partidos= matriz_partidos.drop('column_name', 1)

    time.sleep(10)
except OSError :
    print("No se puede leer el archivo intentelo de nuevo")

    cargar()
aj_data(matriz_partidos)
```

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con "pasar de un csv a una matriz"?¿de un csv a un DataFrame?¿O de un csv a un DataFrame y de este a un array de NumPy? Esa columna es el índice, todo DataFrame de Pandas ha de tener uno. Si tu csv tiene una columna que pueda actuar como índice puedes indicarlo, pero el DataFrame a de tener un índice para poder referenciar las filas del mismo si o si. Si muestras el código que estás usando y un ejemplo del csv es más fácil ayudar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En pandas, cuando cargas un archivo se crea un dataframe el cual asigna automaticamente un index

Este es un ejemplo tomado de la documentacion original https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Como puedes observar  se crea el dataframe y a la izquierda se genera automaticamente un index, te recomiendo probar con `pd.read_csv(ruta, index = False)`